# Template not working for the custom Post type

Tags: custom-post-types, functions

Generally, this is the hierarchal order in which templates will work for the custom post type.

1. single-{post-type}-{slug}.php – (Since 4.4) First, WordPress looks
   for a template for the specific post. For example, if post type is
   product and the post slug is dmc-12, WordPress would look for
   single-product-dmc-12.php.
2. single-{post-type}.php – If the post type is product, WordPress
       would look for single-product.php.
3. single.php – WordPress then falls back to single.php.
4. singular.php – Then it falls back to singular.php.
5. index.php – Finally, as mentioned above, WordPress ultimately falls
       back to index.php.

I have created this template:

```
single-theme.php
```

But the posts pages of the theme CPT are not picking up this template? what could be the issue?

If needed I can update my question with the full CPT function.

I am using this in CPT can this be a culprit:

```
'capability_type'       => 'page',
```

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You registered the post type with the name 'theme'?

Also when changing templates and anything that has any correlation to url-s always reload or load the page admin->settings->permalinks. Sometimes without this, the changes won't take effect.

Comment: Yes, with the name "theme"

Comment: Hmm! The way you suggested me I did, and it worked. Looks like it was a non-issue. what causes this? Is this some cache settings? I am accepting your answer hopefully it will help someone else